# Saving Audit log: File not found

Tags: audit-log-reports

when I save an Audit log I specify a Document Library e.g. /demo/Auditlogs and click OK.
Sharepoint then "works" for a few moments and then returns an error:
"Sorry, something went wrong"
"File not found"

(the wording may not be 100% correct since it is translated from danish :-) )

The logged-on User is Site Collection administrator and is, beside that, also Administrator on the site.
This is Sharepoint 2013 - On premise

Any ideas?

Kind regards
Jacob Clausen

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed in O365 support and community sites, and apparently is a known issue not well documented because of its unreliability and difficulty to replicate.  In my case I've been able to use audit reports exactly twice in two years (not at all this year) in O365/SPOnline, despite having configures multiple auto-reports that ran successfully previously.  I've had a ticket open for most of this year on that subject; my client is not able to run them at all.  Not really a help but confirmation that it exists for others. Good luck.